# Better performance in read/write data structure + byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I am writing a program to compress an image using Huffman encoding and I need to write the data structure and the byte file. After that, I have to read/decode it. I realize that my read and write is very slow.

I think in `writetree()` I need to write either `width`, `height`, `compress` bits and the `tree` data structure. I am not sure we can combine it or not.

And another part, I think I use too many for loop so it is very slow in a very long string

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import json
import sys, string

trim = ('0', ('127', '255'))
width = 4
height = 4
longstring = "1100100111001101011110010011010110101111001001101011010111100100110101101011"

def decode (tree, str) :
    output = ""
    list = []
    p = tree
    count = 0
    for bit in str :
        if bit == '0' : p = p[0]     # Head up the left branch
        else          : p = p[1]     # or up the right branch
        if type(p) == type("") :
            output += p              # found a character. Add to output
            list.append(int(p))
            p = tree                 # and restart for next character

    return list

def writetree(tree,height, width,compress):
    with open('structure.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(trim, outfile)
        outfile.close()
    f = open("info.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(height)+"\n")
    f.write(str(width)+"\n")
    f.write(str(compress)+"\n")
    f.close()

def readtree():
    with open('structure.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    k = open("info.txt", "r")
    heightread = k.readline().strip("\n")
    widthread = k.readline().strip("\n")
    compressread = k.readline().strip("\n")
    json_file.close()
    k.close()
    return tuple(data), int(heightread), int(widthread), int(compressread)

def writefile():
    print("Write file")
    with open('file', 'wb') as f:
        bit_strings = [longstring[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(longstring), 8)]
        byte_list = [int(b, 2) for b in bit_strings]
        print(byte_list)
        realsize = len(bytearray(byte_list))
        print('Compress number of bits: ', len(longstring))
        writetree(trim,height,width,len(longstring))
        f.write(bytearray(byte_list))
        f.close()
def readfile():
    print("Read file")
    byte_list = []
    longbin = ""
    with open('file', 'rb') as f:
        value = f.read(1)
        while value != b'':
            byte_list.append(ord(value))
            value = f.read(1)
    print(byte_list)

    for a in byte_list[:-1]:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:08b}'.format(a)
    trim_read, height_read, width_read , compress_read = readtree()
    sodu = compress_read%8

    '''
    because the this string is split 8 bits at the time, and the current compress_read is 76 
    so the sodu is 4. I have to convert the last byte_list into 4bits not 8 bits
    '''

    if sodu == 0:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:08b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 1:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:01b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 2:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:02b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 3:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:03b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 4:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:04b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 5:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:05b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 6:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:06b}'.format(byte_list[-1])
    elif sodu == 7:
        longbin = longbin + '{0:07b}'.format(byte_list[-1])

    print(longbin)
    print("Decode/ show image:")
    pixels = decode(trim_read, longbin)
    it = iter(pixels)
    pixels = list(zip(it,it,it))
    #print(pixels)

    image_out = Image.new("RGB", (width_read, height_read))
    image_out.putdata(pixels)
    #image_out.show()

writefile()
readfile()
```

Comment: Hello! I think you have a great first post, could you maybe explain quickly how your algorithm works? I think your question might draw more attention, but anyways I think you've done a good job.

Comment: I am using the Huffman encoding, It is quite long to explain in here.

Comment: for now, i need to write file, save the data structure ( trim ) also save the height and width and compress bit of the image. I think I make it loop over and over again so It much slower in longwer string

Comment: You can see in readfile function, I read the file and and append to the list, and loop it again to convert '{0:08b}'.format(a)

Comment: Are you still looking for answers to this? :)